# How to copy over a "single file" (that was created with dd command) using the "dd" command (block-by-block)?

Tags: linux, command

Debian 10; need to copy from external media mounted on Debian 10 to ext media mounted on Ubuntu 18.04.

I am able to use another `dd` command to do this, what the main issue seems to be is what the `if` parameter needs to be. All I have found so far is what the 'if' command is if copying the entire ext media device. `if=/dev/???`?

I have been able to copy over certain external media using the dd command, but the whole ext media had to be copied over.

Now, I just want to copy over a single file. Yes, the single file can take-up the entire destination.

I'm wondering if I can just copy and paste the "already" dd'd created file whereby I used the following command to create this single file that I now need to move to a microSD card.

When this single file is copied, yes, the new file/copy needs to include every block-by-block that the original single file has; a block-by-block replica.

Previous dd command for whole media device:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdx bs=16M of=/path.to.file/create.name
```

The following question is very similar, but I need to know the exact command so that I don't make an error. The flash drive the original "dd'd" file came from may be having some problems so I don't want to have to redo the original dd again unless absolutely necessary.

[Super User: can Linux dd copy a single file from an ext4 formatted partition to an NTFS partition?](https://superuser.com/questions/1376592/can-linux-dd-copy-a-single-file-from-an-ext4-formatted-partition-to-an-ntfs-part)

In the article cited, one comment reads:

> The source in dd if=…, as well as the destination, is always a named file. It might be a virtual "device" file provided by the kernel, but as far as dd knows, it's still just a file.

Maybe I just replace `/dev/sdx` with `/dev/sdx/filename`?

Comment: `if=/path/to/file`?

Comment: @muru so, maybe........" sudo dd if=/dev/sdx/Directory filename bs=16M of=/path.to.file/create.name" ? I left a space before "filename" since it is NOT a directory; maybe I need to connect "Directory & filename" with an underscore (/Directory_filename) ??? But in my original dd command, the "IF" was not mounted and it normally is not supposed to be.

Comment: What path do you use to access the file? Use that.

Comment: @muru Well, the path is simple: /dev/sdx/mnt/ ...........but then there is the filename. Would I connect the "/mnt" to the filename with an underscore? "/mnt_filename" ? Thanks.

Comment: `/` is the path separator in Linux, not underscores. `/mnt/filename`.

Comment: @muru Ok, thanks. I thought I could only use a '/' if a directory followed it. So... "if=/dev/sdx/mnt/filename" ?

Comment: @muru Actually, if I am correct in presuming that "if" can not be mounted, then I am back to what I originally posted in my question: "/dev/sdx/filename". Do you feel this is correct? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you adding `/dev/sdx` there?

Comment: @muru Don't i have to tell it where to look? When it is the whole device the command uses "if=/dev/sdx". Plus, the IF is not mounted.Thx.

Comment: You are telling it where to look by giving it the path: `/mnt/filename` or whatever. Where does `/dev/sdx` come in to the picture?

Comment: @muru I have to tell it what device the file is on, don't I, since the IF is not mounted?

Comment: Then you'll have to mount it first, and use the mount point's path. You can't just directly pick files off a devices.

Comment: @muru I was previously told the dd command will not work if the IF is mounted, but I'll try it.

Comment: That's when you're using the whole device.

Comment: @muru AAAHHHHH! Thanks.

Comment: @muru Thanks - it copied every byte. For anyone in the future who reads this, here is my exact path - "sudo dd if=/directory/name.of.file.to.copy bs=16M of=/file.path.to.directory.copying.to/any.new.name"; note that there is a 'space' after 16M, before the "of".

Comment: @muru I'm going to ask in a new question, unless you would like to mention here, how to open this file as it is referred to as an "unknown kind" of file. Thanks again.